# SQL Server: COUNT by group and total

Tags: sql, sql-server, count

I have sql statement with group by clause as follows:

```
select number , count (*) as 'count' from mytable
group by number
```

Output:

```
number count
1       10
2        5
3        6
```

How should i modify my query to get the total in the table as follows:

```
 number count
    1       10
    2        5
    3        6
   total    21
```

Comment: What database are you using?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As you are probably using SQL Server, you can use `with rollup`:

```
select coalesce([number], 'total') as [number]
     , count(*) as [count]
from [mytable]
group by [number]
with rollup
```

Answer (score 0):

Depending on your particular SQL dialect, you might try something like

```
select number , count (*) as 'count' from mytable
group by number

union

select 'Total' as 'number', count (*) as 'count' from mytable
```

Answer (score 0):

You would need to cast the number column to a char when unioning with the "total" text in the last row. The below syntax `TO_CHAR` would work for Oracle:

```
select TO_CHAR(num) , count (*) as "count" 
from mytable
group by num
union all
select 'total' , sum(count (*)) as "count" 
from mytable
group by num
```

or mysql:

```
select CAST(num as CHAR(10)) , count (*) as "count" 
from mytable
group by num
union all
select 'total' , sum(count (*)) as "count" 
from mytable
group by num
```

Comment: I don't believe `GROUP BY` belongs in the bottom portion of either query, `COUNT(*)` will suffice.